# Ruby integration with mailchimp-api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mailchimp

I'm trying to subscribe a single email to multiple lists with RoR and the official mailchimp-api gem. It works, but the last four values (double_optin, update_existing, replace_interests, and send_welcome) are not updating and I get an error that the email "already exists" even though I'm trying to pass the update_existing as true.  I've written Mailchimp several times and they feel they've reached the end of their assistance.  They have said they are not experts in the wrapper--even if it is the "official" gem--and cannot help me further.  My code looks like this:

```
  responses << mailchimp_lists.each do |ml|
    mailchimp.lists.subscribe(
      ml,
      { "email" => order.customer_email,
        "euid" => order.customer_id,
        "leid" => ""
      },
      { "FNAME"       => order.customer_first_name,
        "LNAME"       => order.customer_last_name,
        "COMPANY"     => order.company_name,
        "ADDRESS1"    => order.billing_address_1,
        "ADDRESS2"    => order.billing_address_2,
        "CITY"        => order.billing_city,
        "STATE"       => order.billing_state,
        "POSTALCODE"  => order.billing_zip,
        "SALUTATION"  => ""
      },
      "html",
      false,
      true,
      false,
      false
      )
  end
```

I've tried sending the last four params in several different ways such as:

```
      "email_type" => "html",
      "double_optin" => false,
```

Or:

```
      {"email_type" => "html"},
      {"double_optin" => false}
```

At times, Mailchimp can see the params arrive in such a way that it seems it should not be triggering an "email already exists" error, but it just won't work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailchimp-api gem's documentation describes the subscribe method as:

```
#subscribe(id, email, merge_vars = nil, email_type = 'html', double_optin = true, update_existing = false, replace_interests = true, send_welcome = false)
```

While the batch_subscribe shows:

```
#batch_subscribe(id, batch, double_optin = true, update_existing = false, replace_interests = true)
```

Note that the batch method does not include a "send_welcome" param.  When I removed it from my list of params for the subscribe method--essentially sending three booleans instead of four as suggested, the update_existing worked perfectly.  Seems like an error in the documentation here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp-api/2.0.4/Mailchimp/Lists#subscribe-instance_method

Hopefully this helps someone else!